# Is there a supported way to run .NET 4.0 applications natively on a Mac?

Tags: c#, .net, mac, mono

What, if any, are the Microsoft supported options for running C#/.NET 4.0 code natively on the Mac? Yes, I know about Mono, but among other things, it lags Microsoft. And Silverlight only works in a web browser. A VMWare-type solution won't cut it either.

Is there any semi-authoritative answer to why Microsoft just doesn't support .NET on the Mac itself? It would seem like they could Silverlight and/or buy Mono and quickly be there. No need for native Visual Studio; cross-compiling and remote debugging is fine.

The reason is that where I work there is a growing amount of Uncertainty about the future which is causing a lot more development to be done in C++ instead of C#; brand new projects are chosing to use C++. Nobody wants to tell management 18–24 months from now "sorry" should the Mac (or iPad) become a requirement. C++ is seen as the safer option, even if it (arguably) means a loss in productivity today.

Comment: Supported by whom?

Comment: Why do you actually care if MS supports it? IMO it should matter more if Apple supports it if you want to target Mac.

Comment: Going with C++ is not a bad idea. You can have a portable code base and use the native GUI's on each platform.

Comment: To update this post it looks like MS has taken notice and they will start to support .NET on different OS's though it's not clear how this will be done. You can create cross platform applications with .NET using NOV: https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision.aspx (I work for this company). It generally allows you to code in C# on windows and then compile for Wpf, MAC, Silverlight and soon for iOS and Android. There is a free (community) edition of this product so there is no need to sacrifice productivity and stick with arcane C++.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> is there any semi-authoritative answer
>   to why Microsoft just doesn't support
>   .NET on the Mac itself?

The best answer is probably that you don't "just support" .NET on the Mac.  You spend hundreds of millions of dollars and several years porting .NET to the Mac.

While some things are fully managed and would not require porting, most things are wrappers around the Win32 API (windows, controls, gdi+, cryptography, active directory, COM, enterprise services, device access, sound, video, codecs, winforms, etc, etc).

Every single one of these would have to be abstracted in the backend and remapped to equivalent native libraries on OSX.  Of course, there's not going to be a nice clean mapping, so you also have to write hacks upon hacks to get it functioning exactly the same.

Then there's the issue that these APIs on OSX can be brittle and Apple isn't very good at backwards compatibility, so you get to redo your hacks with every major release (and sometimes minor release and hotfixes), racking up a high maintenance cost.

Basically, it's a tremendous amount of money and work for very little gain on a platform whose owner would be against you doing it anyways.  And you don't really want to spend money to help people migrate off of your own platform onto a competitor's.

So you are left with not-perfect cross-platform choices:

- C++, which will still require porting in the future
- Silverlight out of the browser, for Microsoft support
- Mono, which does the work to support a healthy subset of .NET, but isn't Microsoft

Comment: `You spend hundreds of millions of dollars and several years porting .NET to the Mac.` Excuse me? That number sounds a little high...I'm pretty sure the Mono-Framework (with support for many more OSs) didn't cost that much.

Comment: @Dan: Exactly, Microsoft does not want to be compatible with the world, otherwise the world could use something different. ;)

Comment: The Mono framework is also not a complete, fully tested, documented, supported solution. There is a difference in what's "good enough" for open source and the quality people expect from Microsoft.  It would easily cost hundreds of millions of dollars for them to do it to the level users would demand.  What they could do to lessen the investment would be to pick out a popular (and portable) subset of the .NET framework and just do it.  That's what they chose to do, they call it "Silverlight".

Comment: @Dan Source? Last I checked they had only ported a small subset, not even close to the full framework. As jpobst said, porting a subset is feasible but porting the full framework, including a high quality GUI library is very expensive.

Answer (score 14):

No, Silverlight is the only *Microsoft* option from .Net on OS X. Mono does not "lag" as much as you think; it supports .Net 4.0 and C# 4, for example. However, the UI toolkits (WinForms and WPF) are not well supported on OS X. Mono doesn't support WPF at all. Neither could Microsoft without rewriting the entire rendering engine. That's probably OK, though. If you want to write a native Mac app, you should be writing a native UI (perhaps using MonoMac).

Comment: @Dan: The way Mono moves these days, if you start developing an app for the latest version of .NET when Microsoft releases it, Mono will support that same version by the time that app is ready to ship.

Comment: @Dan SL and WPF under the covers are attempting to merge as much as possible. There are technical differences but the fundamental concepts are cross platform.

Comment: If your companies management is not willing to use Mono then you will be unable make a desktop application written in traditional C# 4.0 its just that simple.

Answer (score 5):

No.  Mono's your best bet.

Other open source projects like DotGNU may serve you as well. http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu/  But none of these is MSFT supported.

Answer (score 4):

Silverlight is not *browser only*. Since version 3 [OOB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882515.aspx) has existed and would be the route I would take if a Microsoft supported platform is a must-have.

While Mono may lag it is not as removed from the .NET stack as you may think and should not be cast aside as a viable option.

As to why Microsoft does not implement the entire .NET stack; ROI.

Comment: SL is not the entire .NET stack. The SL runtime versus the entire .NET stack are completely different animals.

Comment: @Dan When companies are pushing things to the cloud...the last thing that you want to do is port a stack over that can't run in the cloud. SL can run across browsers. You can argue with the likes of Google and others the push for working within a browser is real. Why at this moment would you then opt to port an entire stack to an OS with < 10% market share along with virtualization so prevalent in this day and age?

Comment: @Dan If it can run in a browser your good to go...or so we thought...with Apple stopping support of Flash. There is a reason these frameworks exist; to make life easier. To provide functionality which 9 times out of 10 does not exist within the standard. While you may feel safe in a C++ environment in terms of portability...you'll feel pain (lots of it) in other ways. Since you mention the iPad...you'll be on all the Android tablets as well right? Don't want to leave any sub 10% market share for the taking.

Answer (score 3):

Most of Microsoft’s profit comes from two products - Windows and Office. Cross platform compatibility would hurt Windows.

If you really want the same code running cross platform, write a web app. It doesn't sound like you do though. “Just in case” isn’t a good reason, it’s scope creep.

Even if you do decide to target Mac OS X or iOS in 16 months from now, do you really think you could take your existing C++ code and turn it into a good (or even functional) native app? Unless you're working on a full-screen game, the answer’s no.

Save time with C# now, and if you decide to move onto the Mac, rewrite it the Mac way with Objective-C and Cocoa - your users will thank you.

Comment: Assuming the interface code is properly separated, it will be easier to move C++ code onto the Mac.  Rewrite the interface in Objective-C using Cocoa, link to the rest, and you've got a whole lot of the job done.

Comment: These cross-platform concerns right here is why a lot of us are still using Java and not moving to C#.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any semi-authoritative answer to why Microsoft just doesn't support .NET on the Mac itself?

Where's the market that would justify MS spending the treasure coding it?  In order to do this, they'd have to drop serious cash--millions of dollars in salary.  An ongoing process, as fixes and updates come along.

And for what?  Bragging rights?  All they get out of it is the ability for people to ditch Windows for Apple and be able to still run their apps.

If anyone would profit from doing this, it would be Apple.  Make it easier for people to transition to their platform and for developers (DEVELOPERS DEVELOPERS) to code on it.  But do you think SJ gives a crap?  They'd rather invent new stuff to stick an **i** infront of.  Besides, most of the framework is OS and the CLR specs are free for anybody to implement.  You can't stick a filthy NDA on any of it.

Comment: Mono is an open source platform, and while the source for .NET has been released, the .NET Framework is NOT open source. Microsoft will be unable to purchase Mono, for many reasons, the major one is that they do not have a single 100% open source application. Do you know know that Silverlight is only a single language within the .NET and the reason it is multi-platform because Microsoft would like it to be a replacement for Flash. I should also add that Apple has made hand movements towards not even allowing something this on their operating system.

Comment: @Ramhound "Open Source" as in [you can view it without breaking any kind of license](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx), not as in some neckbeard in Shamokin Dam can fork it, prepend "Awesome" to every class name, and release it as "Awesome.NET".

Comment: @Dan sounds like the solution to your woes isn't "one language to rule them all" but "How do we deploy in a platform-agnostic manner."  Most people are accomplishing this by breaking the UI from the logic, embedding one on a per-platform basis and the other as a service on the innertubes.

Comment: @Dan I have a solution for that... Don't code for the Mac.  I have a personal Non Develop-for-Apple Agreement I wrote and signed myself.  I would utterly hate not being able to code C#, and so avoid doing so.  But sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do, and if wishes were fishes we'd have to think up some other alliteration to describe the many things we want but cannot have.

Comment: @Dan kindasorta.  They haven't really touched the desktop (yet).  But I am amazed at what a difference five years makes.

Answer (score 0):

You might find the MonoMac project useful - http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac

It allows for developing Cocoa applications Mono style, which can be deployed to the Mac App store.

I would strongly consider this approach for a developer unfamiliar with Objective-C but with .NET/Mono/Java who has to deliver an application in a time restrained scenario.

Answer (score 0):

None.

I recommend either writing a cross-compilable C++ application - may you have joy in it - or using Ruby with wxWidgets.

I consider .NET a bad proposition for cross-platform development and long-term product maintenance. Although, man, you can whiz out apps fast in it. :-/

Wish Delphi was still a major contender.

Comment: Ever heard of Lazarus?

Comment: Also, ever head of Java?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run .NET natively on a Mac, you can use BootCamp to do this (i.e. you run Windows on the Mac, and your .NET applications in Windows).

If you meant Mac OS X rather than just the hardware, then you can use VMWare or Parallels to run the .NET applications in Windows (in emulation) in OS X. Both have visual modes that let your application appear as if it is running only within OS X (it will look and behave like a Windows application, but if you are writing a cross-platform non-web application without a custom interface for each OS you will always have that problem).

You will get the same amount of "support" by doing this, since you're running the app in Windows, albeit virtualized. Of course, anyone running the app will need a copy of the virtualization software, and Windows, and be willing to put up with an app that doesn't behave like an OS X app - but it is the only way to have "native" .NET running on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Dan, I don't think you can do this. However, a possible solution (still vapourware) is to use Embarcadero  Rad Studio C++ Builder, which has a nice VCL for developing visual applications (upon which much of .net is based), and they are RUMOURED to have cross-platform support coming out in the next release.

This will be develop on windows, target to Mac or Linux. Or so their roadmap says.

The C++ environment is reasonable and if you develop against the VCL then in theory the application will just work on the other platforms.

Of course until its actually shipped it remains to be seen how effective this really is.

Answer (score -2):

The answer is no.

Actually your case seems to be a very good example of when *not* to choose .NET.

Comment: @Dan: And the point is?  You seem to be agreeing with me...?

Answer (score -3):

If you want to develop for an OS then use the right tools. There are no truly professional apps written in mono for the Mac. There is on the other hand a lot of non-professional developers using a lot of tools creating a lot of garbage. Look at the mono app reviews that have been written for OSX. The developers are writing using an incomplete framework hacked to match the OSX platform. Start out write - if you have used C# Objective C is a quick learn.

Professional developers for the mac use C++, Objective C, Cocoa, and Xcode. I develop on several platforms and each has their own best tools. Use Xcode for the Mac and iOS.

Just as a side note Xcode is no Visual Studio it is not as stable and is a disgrace to apple in comparison, but it works well when you get used to he quirks. It is very difficult to beat Microsofts tools - but they were written for Windows not Linux, iOS, OSX, AIX etc.

Comment: Do you have any facts to backup statements like "Xcode is not as stable and is a disgrace to Apple" because based on my own personal experience everyone that has used Xcode has loved it. Besides even after you express your personal opinion on a subject it seems your not familar with, you are not even aware that in 2013, there actually is a solution. Of course the solution is actually `Mono` and `Xamarin.Mac` but it is a solution.  The current version of Mono is nearly a 100% full implementation of .NET 4.0 it only lacks a couple major features which likely will never be ported ( i.e. WPF ).